# Reading chars from input

Tags: java, arrays, char

This is an exercise training for University. The program is about counting/reading the number of squares on a sheet (where the size is given by the user) the squares are represented by '#' and empty space is '.'.

```
public class Quadrado {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int flag=0, l=0, c=0;
        String bla;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        flag = in.nextInt();
        l = in.nextInt();
        c = in.nextInt();
        char [][] folha = new char[l][c];
        while(in.hasNext()==true){
        for (int i=0; i<l; i++){
            for (int x=0; x<c; x++){
                bla = in.nextLine();
                folha[i][x] = bla.charAt(x);
            }
        }
        }

        if(flag==1){
            contador(folha,in);
        }

    }


    public static void contador(char[][] folha, Scanner in){
        int conta=0, l=0, c=0;
        for (int i=0; i<l; i++){
            for (int x=0; x<c; x++){
                if (folha[i][x]=='#'){
                    conta++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(conta);
        }
}
```

So eclipse was giving me errors on the `folha[i][x] = bla.charAt(x)`, at first I had it like this: `folha[i][x] = in.next().charAt(x)`, but it was giving an error that I don't recall, so my friend said to use the object like it is now, but it still goes wrong. When you execute it, it lets you insert the flag and the size of the sheet but as soon as you finish inserting the first line ex: `###` it gives me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at Quadrado.main(Quadrado.java:21)
```

It was also giving me an error when calling the method and the suggested solution by eclipse was creating the same method.

Hope you guys can guide me here.

Comment: Please add information about the *full input* you use (including the `flag`, `l` and `c`). What is `flag`?

Comment: I'd start by naming my variables more descriptively than `bla`.

Comment: You should move your 'bla = in.nextLine();'. To the outer loop. You'll loose data of the input if you keep it in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

You will get `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` when `bla.length()` will be less than the value of `c`.

because your this line is wrong

```
folha[i][x] = bla.charAt(x);
```

you should check `x< bla.length()` before  this line.